# Angular 5 Unit Testing cannot read property 'http' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am attempting to write a helper function in an Angular test leveraging `HttpTestingController`.  The reason being is because I will eventually have a series of endpoints within my Angular service, `RequestService`, that I want to test within this testing file.  I do not want to repeatedly inject my `RequestService` and `HttpTestingController` instances into each test function that tests the service.  That is redundant.  Rather, I would prefer to have a single test function that takes the injected `RequestService` and `HttpTestingController` instances and repeatedly passes them into the helper function I have created, `requestHelper`.  This way when I want to test additional endpoints, all I need to do is make a call to the helper function and provide the parameters that are needed.

The problem I am bumping into is that when the helper function runs, the service's instance for some reason does not appear to exist,  Even though the test is able to access the service's functions.  When it reaches my service method's call to the `http.get` within the `callEndpoint` function, it gives me the below error:

`Failed: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined`

This does not make sense to me because the `this` keyword is referring to the instance of the Angular service, and the test case is able to reach the service's function, so how could `this` possibly be undefined?

Here is my test spec:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpRequest, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {  RequestService } from './request.service';

describe(`RequestService`, () => {

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            HttpClientModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
          ],
          providers: [
            RequestService
          ]
        });
      }));

      afterEach(async(inject([HttpTestingController], (backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        backend.verify();
      })));

      it(`TESTING INJECTION`, async(inject([RequestService, HttpTestingController],
        (service: RequestService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {

         requestHelper(service.callEndpoint,'https://endpointurl.com',backend);
      })));

      function requestHelper(serviceCall: Function, url: string,  backendInstance: any) {
        serviceCall(...serviceParams).subscribe();
        backendInstance.expectOne((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
          return req.url === url
              && req.method === 'GET';
        }, 'GET');
      }
});
```

And the respective service that the spec is testing

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class RequestService {

      private requestOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Locale': 'en_US'})
      };

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      callEndpoint(state: string, countryCode: string): Observable<Object> {
        return this.http.get(`https://endpointurl.com`,this.requestOptions);
      }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like `this` is undefined.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Correct.  But how can that be possible?  Especially considering this test spec is able to access the service's functions?  Indicating that the instance does exist..it is just that when the helper function runs the service call, it somehow gets to that function and suddenly the instance is undefined when the call to `this` is made.  Or perhaps the keyword itself is undefined?  I do not know if that makes sense..  I am not sure at this point.

Comment: have you tried passing `requestHelper(service.callEndpoint.bind(service)...` ?

Comment: Adding .bind(service) to service.callEndpoint when passing it as a param to requestHelper should solve the issue

Comment: @BorisLobanov This did in fact solve the issue.  Thank you!  Would one of you like to post it as an answer? I will accept it. :)

Comment: @CarlosRincones

Comment: I just did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the context in the `it` block:

```
it(`TESTING INJECTION`, async(inject([RequestService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: RequestService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {

    requestHelper(service.callEndpoint.bind(service),'https://endpointurl.com',backend);
})));
```